# Cross-platform MIDI in the website

Tags: javascript, html, midi, quicktime

I'm creating an ear training website for musicians. In PHP, it generates simple MIDI file with an error (out-of-tune tone) which the user has to correct. It saves the MIDI file and the user should play it. Here, the funny part begins.

**Problems:**

- I **have to** use MIDI, because the exercises are created on-the-fly with
  random errors.
- I **cannot** convert it to mp3/ogg serverside since webhostings usually don't come with timidity and lame bundled (correct me if I'm wrong). The site is gonna be non-profit (or very low-profit at best), so dedicated hosting is not an option.
- There are billions of possible combinations, so preparing one large audio file is not possible.
- The playback **should be** cross-platform.
- I **would like to** have control over the playback via JS.

**What I tried:**

- `<embed>` and `<object>` - this way you let browser choose the plugin. It's inconsistent and you lose most control over the playback (not mentioning the visual side)
- `<audio>` - doesn't support MIDI at all
- QuickTime in combination with antique AC_QuickTime.js 1.2, which uses `<embed>` and `<object>` dynamically - but **I don't want to annoy users** with installing extra plugin.

**Question:**

Is there any other approach/technology I could use?

Comment: Perhaps this approach is appropriate: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Complete_Example%3a_Creating_a_Web_Based_Tone_Generator ?

Comment: Or why not have a single mp3/ogg file of a much longer length that contains 100's of different tones and you can use a HTML5 audio element to play specific "chunks" of the audio?

Comment: Does "other approach" include "write a 'real' application"?

Comment: You don't have to use MIDI at all to generate music dynamically.  I would suggest doing the entire thing client-side in JavaScript.  You can create a sampler pretty easily with the Web Audio API, and play back your notes with precise timing.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I cannot make one large file, see updated question. Real application :) Maybe I'll do it when I get frustrated enough. Anyway, **Web Audio API** looks great. However, according to their [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API#Browser_compatibility) it doesn't work in IE at all. Whatever I think of that browser, I dont want to exclude so many users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally set up a VPS, installed timidity and lame and everything works like charm. Results here: [yesmaestro.com](http://yesmaestro.com)